# FFmpeg cannot find codec parameters for yuv420p stream

Tags: ios, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am trying to use FFmpeg (with IJKPlayer) to stream an RTSP stream from a camera. I am trying to do this on iOS, so I compiled FFmpeg by myself.

However, when I try to play the stream, it seems to produce an error:

> Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, 1 reference
>   frame, none(left)): unspecified size Consider increasing the value for
>   the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options

Further down, the stream information displayed is as follows:

```
  Metadata:
    title           : streamed by the Santachi RTSP server
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/90000: Video: h264, 1 reference frame, none(left), 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1, 0, 1/8000: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
```

For reference, when I try to connect to the stream from my PC, it works, and the stream info I get is as follows:

```
  Metadata:
    title           : streamed by the Santachi RTSP server
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 28, 1/90000: Video: h264 (Main), 1 reference frame, yuv420p(progressive, left), 1280x720, 0/1, 20 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1, 17, 1/8000: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
```

Seeing that the codec is yuv420p, I recompiled FFmpeg with the following options included:

```
COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-decoder=yuv4"
COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=yuv4mpegpipe"
```

H264 decoder and parser are already enabled. However, the result was the same. Also, other streams, from different sources seem to work fine. It's just this particular camera's stream that doesn't work.

Since it seems that FFmpeg, when compiled correctly, can consume the stream, it seems that I am missing some options when compiling it, but I have no idea which options. Any help?

Comment: What probesize and analyzeduration values did you try?

Comment: @Mulvya 9999000000000 for  both. That didn't make a difference. I am testing right now as well, and other streams, which have yuv420p format seem to work fine (like this one rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov). So I am starting to wonder whether this is the problem at all.

Comment: You placed both options *before* the input ?

Comment: @Mulvya I am using IJKPlayer, which uses FFmpeg. I don't know how IJK passes the params to FFmpeg. What I am doing is something like this - `[options setFormatOptionIntValue:9999000000000 forKey:@"analyzeduration"];`. The `options` object is then passed to IJK. Do you think these options can actually help? If so, I can try and dig into the sources to see what's going on in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by switching to VLCKit (available as a Pod for iOS). Although it still uses ffmpeg underneath, it does some "magic" with the stream and it seems to work fine.